# Zoom in messes up Canvas Area Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

A simplified version of my page is reproduced below. Clicking on a circle, in the demo below, should print out the name of the circle clicked in a div. I have 2 issues.
 1) When I zoom in on the page (Chrome seems to do this automatically on my page when it's loaded, so I currently have to zoom out for the clickable area to work when using the Chrome browser), the by-pixel click detection no longer works. I detect whether a click happens within one of the three circles by checking the distance (in pixel) from the center of the circle. You could try zooming in and seeing if clicking on the circles produces the expected results.

2) The text on the right of the circles sometimes are not displayed, and I have to manually refresh the page once (after it is first loaded) to see the text appear alongside the circles.

The code that defines the click is at the bottom of the script section.
I recommend viewing the page below in a full page.

```js
var total_vap_count = 12;
var total_sta_count = 3;


//ac
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(175,50,30,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = "#004379";
ctx.font = "14px Lato";
if ("1" < 2){
    ctx.fillText("1" + " AC", 211, 50);
} else {
    ctx.fillText("2" + " ACs", 211, 50);
}
ctx.fill();




//sta
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(175,300,30,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = "#004379";
ctx.font = "14px Lato";
if (total_sta_count < 2){
    ctx.fillText("" + total_sta_count + " device", 211, 300);
} else {
    ctx.fillText("" + total_sta_count + " devices", 211, 300);
}
ctx.fillText("connected", 211, 315);
ctx.fill();

//ssid
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50,175,30,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = "#004379";
ctx.font = "14px Lato";
if (total_vap_count < 2){
    ctx.fillText("" + total_vap_count + " SSID", 86, 175);
} else {
    ctx.fillText("" + total_vap_count + " SSIDs", 86, 175);
}
ctx.fill();




// ssid status
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50 + Math.sin(Math.PI/4) * 30,175-Math.cos(Math.PI/4) * 30,8,0,2*Math.PI);
if (total_vap_count){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#4caf50";
} else {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
}
ctx.fill();

// sta status
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(175 + Math.sin(Math.PI/4) * 30,300 - Math.cos(Math.PI/4) * 30,8,0,2*Math.PI);
if (total_sta_count){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#4caf50";
} else {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
}
ctx.fill();

// ac status
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(175 + Math.sin(Math.PI/4) * 30,50 - Math.cos(Math.PI/4) * 30,8,0,2*Math.PI);
if (parseInt("1") > 0){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#4caf50";
} else {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
}
//ctx.fillStyle = "#e9ebee";
ctx.fill();

// Lines.
if (parseInt("1") > 0){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(50 + Math.sin(Math.PI/4) * 30+10,175-Math.cos(Math.PI/4) * 30-10);
    ctx.lineTo(175 - Math.sin(Math.PI/4) * 30-5,50 + Math.cos(Math.PI/4) * 30+5);
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#004379"
    ctx.stroke();
}

if (total_vap_count && total_sta_count){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(50 + Math.sin(Math.PI/4) * 30+5,175+Math.cos(Math.PI/4) * 30+ 5);
    ctx.lineTo(175 - Math.sin(Math.PI/4) * 30-5,300 - Math.cos(Math.PI/4) * 30-5);
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#004379"
    ctx.stroke();
}






$(document).ready(function() {

 var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    var paint1 = setTimeout(()=>{
        ctx.font="16px FontAwesome";
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText('\uf0ac',170, 55);
    },2000);

    
    var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    var paint2 = setTimeout(()=>{
        ctx.font="16px FontAwesome";
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText('\uf10b',170, 305);
    },2000);

 
    var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    var paint3 = setTimeout(()=>{
        ctx.font="16px FontAwesome";
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText('\uf012',45, 180);
    },2000);


    $('#myCanvas').click(function(e){
        var x = e.clientX;
        var y = e.clientY;
        console.log("inside click");
        console.log(x);
        console.log(y);
        //x start: 5, y start: 213 for canvas
        if (Math.pow(x-55, 2) + Math.pow(y-175-213, 2) < Math.pow(30, 2)){
            //$j("#overview_page").hide();
            //openNav();
            $("#demo").empty().append("ssid clicked");
            
        }

        if (Math.pow(x-175, 2) + Math.pow(y-300-213, 2) < Math.pow(30, 2)){
            //$j("#overview_page").hide();
            //openNav_sta();
            $("#demo").empty().append("sta clicked");
            
        }

        if (Math.pow(x-175, 2) + Math.pow(y-50-213, 2) < Math.pow(30, 2)){
            //$j("#overview_page").hide();
            //openNav_ac();
            $("#demo").empty().append("ac clicked");
        }


    });

})
```

```css
#left_menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 330px;
    background-color: #e9ebee;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #e9ebee;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #008b10;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<ul id="left_menu">
        <li><div><a id="tab_wireless" href="#"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;System Status</a></div></li>
        <li><div><a id="tab_system" href="#"><i class="fa fa-laptop" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Network Configuration</a></div></li>

  <li><div><a id="radio_list" href="#"><i class="fas fa-broadcast-tower"></i>&nbsp;Radio Information</a></div></li>
  <!--<li><a id="search" href="#">Search</a></li>-->
  <li><canvas id="myCanvas" width="310" height="400" style="position: relative; top: 110px; left: 5px;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas></li>
</ul>





<div id="demo" style="margin-left:330px;padding:1px 16px;border:1px solid #e9ebee; border-radius:6px;">hello world</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used `offsetX` and `offsetY` here as a quick fix, but you would need a safer way to get the mouse click position relative to the canvas if you want this on production. You need to get the mouse position that is [0, 0] when you click on the left top corner of the canvas.

```js
var total_vap_count = 12;
var total_sta_count = 3;


//ac
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(175,50,30,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = "#004379";
ctx.font = "14px Lato";
if ("1" < 2){
    ctx.fillText("1" + " AC", 211, 50);
} else {
    ctx.fillText("2" + " ACs", 211, 50);
}
ctx.fill();




//sta
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(175,300,30,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = "#004379";
ctx.font = "14px Lato";
if (total_sta_count < 2){
    ctx.fillText("" + total_sta_count + " device", 211, 300);
} else {
    ctx.fillText("" + total_sta_count + " devices", 211, 300);
}
ctx.fillText("connected", 211, 315);
ctx.fill();

//ssid
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50,175,30,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = "#004379";
ctx.font = "14px Lato";
if (total_vap_count < 2){
    ctx.fillText("" + total_vap_count + " SSID", 86, 175);
} else {
    ctx.fillText("" + total_vap_count + " SSIDs", 86, 175);
}
ctx.fill();




// ssid status
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50 + Math.sin(Math.PI/4) * 30,175-Math.cos(Math.PI/4) * 30,8,0,2*Math.PI);
if (total_vap_count){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#4caf50";
} else {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
}
ctx.fill();

// sta status
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(175 + Math.sin(Math.PI/4) * 30,300 - Math.cos(Math.PI/4) * 30,8,0,2*Math.PI);
if (total_sta_count){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#4caf50";
} else {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
}
ctx.fill();

// ac status
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(175 + Math.sin(Math.PI/4) * 30,50 - Math.cos(Math.PI/4) * 30,8,0,2*Math.PI);
if (parseInt("1") > 0){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#4caf50";
} else {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
}
//ctx.fillStyle = "#e9ebee";
ctx.fill();

// Lines.
if (parseInt("1") > 0){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(50 + Math.sin(Math.PI/4) * 30+10,175-Math.cos(Math.PI/4) * 30-10);
    ctx.lineTo(175 - Math.sin(Math.PI/4) * 30-5,50 + Math.cos(Math.PI/4) * 30+5);
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#004379"
    ctx.stroke();
}

if (total_vap_count && total_sta_count){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(50 + Math.sin(Math.PI/4) * 30+5,175+Math.cos(Math.PI/4) * 30+ 5);
    ctx.lineTo(175 - Math.sin(Math.PI/4) * 30-5,300 - Math.cos(Math.PI/4) * 30-5);
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#004379"
    ctx.stroke();
}






$(document).ready(function() {

 var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    var paint1 = setTimeout(()=>{
        ctx.font="16px FontAwesome";
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText('\uf0ac',170, 55);
    },2000);

    
    var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    var paint2 = setTimeout(()=>{
        ctx.font="16px FontAwesome";
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText('\uf10b',170, 305);
    },2000);

 
    var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    var paint3 = setTimeout(()=>{
        ctx.font="16px FontAwesome";
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText('\uf012',45, 180);
    },2000);


    $('#myCanvas').click(function(e){
        var x = e.offsetX;
        var y = e.offsetY;

        //x start: 5, y start: 213 for canvas
        if (pointInCircle(x, y, 50, 175, 30)){
            //$j("#overview_page").hide();
            //openNav();
            $("#demo").empty().append("ssid clicked");
            
        }

        if (pointInCircle(x, y, 175, 300, 30)){
            //$j("#overview_page").hide();
            //openNav_sta();
            $("#demo").empty().append("sta clicked");
            
        }

        if (pointInCircle(x, y, 175, 50, 30)){
            //$j("#overview_page").hide();
            //openNav_ac();
            $("#demo").empty().append("ac clicked");
        }


    });

})

function pointInCircle(x, y, cx, cy, radius) {
  var distancesquared = (x - cx) * (x - cx) + (y - cy) * (y - cy);
  return distancesquared <= radius * radius;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="310" height="400" style="position: relative; top: 110px; left: 5px;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>

<div id="demo"></div>
```